# Is there a way to skip the tutorial?

Tags: two-point-hospital

I find the first tutorial level in two point hospital a bit slow paced. Is there a way to skip it?

Comment: No. There isn't a way to skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. At the start of the game, only Hogsport, Lower Bullocks and Flottering are visible but the last two are not yet accessible. You must get 1 star in each one before unlocking the next.

Yes, it's a bit of a pain, but getting 1 star in Hogsport should take less than 10 minutes with fast-forward and prioritising light-headed patients in the GP queues.